# refresh screen trouble android appcelerator

Tags: android, screen, appcelerator

I have a trouble on Android with Titanium SDK 5.3.0.GA ...

When I click on a button and a full view is opened on the screen in the top (transparent wrapper with another view with some content inside), the screen is refreshed only on the top left of the application and not every where (As you can see on the picture).

This is very strange and I don't have this trouble on iPhone... But when I open the menu with the button, the screen is refreshing well and the wrapper is showed normaly..

Any one now why it's not working when I click on the button ?

Thank you for your help

**Trouble that I have in the image**

[image: Trouble that I have in the image]

**What normally has to be shown on the screen**

[image]

My wrapper look like :

```
wrapper = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor : 'transparent',
    height : 'auto',
    width : 'auto'
});

tView = Ti.UI.createView({
    opacity : 0.8,
    width : 'auto',
    height : 'auto',
    backgroundColor : '#000000'
});

tView2 = Ti.UI.createScrollView({
    width : '90%',
    height : '70%',
    top : '28%',
    backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius : 20,
    showVerticalScrollIndicator : true

});

tView2.add(lRestriction);

wrapper.add(tView);
wrapper.add(tView2);
wrapper.add(btnCloseRestriction);
win.add(wrapper);`
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a view size issue. What is your view set for as far as size? (ie. height/width)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. As you can see, there are 'auto'

Comment: I tried to put '100%' instead of 'auto', but.. this is not changing the problem

Comment: try Ti.UI.FILL for both height and width.

Comment: this is still not :-(

Comment: Maybe you could post all the code and I could cut/paste to see if I can replicate your issue...

Comment: What I have check is this is working well with Android 5.0.0 but this is not working with the last Android version 6.0.0... any one know why? 

I have post my code in my question with how I open the wrapper

Comment: Took your code, ran on 6, works as expected. So, something else is causing your problem. That's why I asked for all your code, not just the little snippet.

Comment: I tried to create a test with just the minimum and this is working....... So it could be a problem with my code... or with drawer ? do you know this plugin ?

Comment: I have a video about my problem here : https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-4047